# Swift 3 Use of unresolved identifier 'clearColor'

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a app in Swift 3 and am trying to make the background of a  WebView clear.This is my code I'm using:

```
    ytWebView.isOpaque = false;
    ytWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

But on the second line I am getting the error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'clearColor'

Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: Use `UIColor.clear`.

Comment: Are you copying this code from somewhere else or converting a project? You are using Objective-C syntax.

Comment: This is not Swift (except `false)`.

Answer (score 2):

`[UIColor clearColor]` is the Objective-C syntax, use `UIColor.clear` in Swift3 :

```
ytWebView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Comment: It's not just that it's Objective-C syntax; `UIColor.clearColor` was the name in previous versions of Swift. It was changed to `UIColor.clear` in (I believe) Swift 3.

Comment: Yes, swift before the version 3 used `clearColor`